How do I convert my ttkbootstrap app code that uses external csv files to a regular app?
I have a app that I created using pycharm. I used ttkbootstrap to create the app and I want to know how I can convert that to a regular app. Here is a picture of how my project is organized below. I tried to learn on youtube but I couldn't understand anything. If anyone could help or lead me in the right direction that would be helpful. I'm using windows.


You can use PyInstaller to package your application into an executable.  Note that it is not actually convert your application to an executable.

If you want to compile your project into a .exe file, you can try PyInstaller.
Just install PyInstaller in your environment with pip install pyinstaller and then, you can call the command pyinstaller --onefile main.py and pyinstaller will import all the dependencies of all the .py files itself, but not the csv files.
To package with the csv files folder, you can specify in the main.spec file that the command above will generate, and then call the command with main.spec instead of main.py pyinstaller --onefile main.spec. Here's a solution for how you can do it.
You can see all the options of the command in the documentation, and all the parameters for the spec file: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files.
I hope I helped!
